# How to activate clock on lock screen?

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens, 6.0-marshmallow

I am using Android 6.0 / Cyanogenmod 13.

Somehow I have deactivated the clock on my lock screen and I can not find the place where to activate it.

Now I have only the unlock pattern there, the place for the clock above is free.

How to activate the clock?

Comment: Try Settings > Lock Screen

Comment: That was the first place I looked. Nothing about a clock or any widgets there...

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are searching is known as **daydream**. You must have changed its setting while doing something in settings. It can be any place but generally found under display setting.

Comment: Really? From what I understand we're talking about different things here. Daydream is the "screensaver" that can be triggered anywhere when docked / plugged in; lockscreen clock is what's shown on the lockscreen itself.

Comment: Hmm... I thought it's about clock daydream. Since I faced something like this before. So 

Answer (score -3):

It is currently impossible to have a clock above the pin/pattern lock screen on android 5, 6 or 7. There is no work around yet.

Comment: Please stop including unnecessary profanity in your posts. And, instead of posting duplicate answers, flag the questions as a duplicate.